# Why is node tool deleting unselected points in lines?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, trace

I am freehand editing lines to a shapefile on Mac QGIS 2.2.0, and have my snap settings at vertex and segment @ 20 pixels. The lines are roadways and I have merged them all into one feature and merged the attributes too.

When attempting to delete a handful of points together (by clicking and dragging), I noticed that points in lines way up north somewhere are also deleted. So I tried exiting, re-starting, and zooming out to see if it happened again. The extra nodes that are deleted are not selected. Also, when trying to delete the target points one by one, *different* points are deleted up north too, also one by one. It is as if they were somehow linked.

What could account for this?